# NSConstraint.constant checking its value after setting to avoid animating view again

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout

I have a `UITextfield` (email) and a `UILabel` (email error messages) - see image

[image]

When I enter an invalid email, I animate in the `UILabel` in by changing a constraint (linked with IBOutlet - default setting 22 in IB is overridden in viewDidLoad to 0) from 0 to 22. This works perfectly.

When I enter a valid email, the reverse happens. This also works perfectly.

I'm having trouble with finding a way to not animate the `UILabel` in *even if it is already there* 
my code is below:

```
   self.usernameErrorMessage.text = @"Invalid Email";

    NSLog(@"before constant: %f", self.emailErrorMessageLabelHeightConstraint.constant);
    NSLog(@"before email textfield height: %f", self.usernameErrorMessage.bounds.size.height);

    if (self.emailErrorMessageLabelHeightConstraint.constant != 22) {

        self.emailErrorMessageLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 22;
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

            NSLog(@"after constant: %f", self.emailErrorMessageLabelHeightConstraint.constant);
            NSLog(@"after email textfield height: %f", self.usernameErrorMessage.bounds.size.height);

            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
```

output of NSLog after running for the first time & entering an invalid email

```
2014-03-19 14:10:44.085 login[21743:60b] before constant: 0.000000
2014-03-19 14:10:44.086 login[21743:60b] before email textfield height: 0.000000
2014-03-19 14:10:47.341 login[21743:60b] after constant: 22.000000
2014-03-19 14:10:47.341 login[21743:60b] after email textfield height: 22.000000
```

clicking back into the textfield to run the code above again (this time I expect the animation to not happen since the error message `UILabel` is already showing... but it just animates back in since for the constant when checked in the if statement is 0.000000 still...

output of the second run

```
2014-03-19 14:15:01.074 login[21743:60b] before constant: 0.000000
2014-03-19 14:15:01.074 login[21743:60b] before email textfield height: 0.000000
2014-03-19 14:15:01.865 login[21743:60b] after constant: 22.000000
2014-03-19 14:15:01.866 login[21743:60b] after email textfield height: 22.000000
```

Comment: It sounds like some other code must be setting your constant back to 0. Are you sure you're not re-setting it in `updateConstraints`?

Comment: I just went through all my code and IB, double checked all the constraints etc.. I didn't see anything out of the ordinary but it seems to be working now. Thanks for the advice on checking everything and not re-setting it. It seems to be working now...